# How to compute the algorithmic space complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory, quicksort, mergesort

I am reviewing my data structures and algorithm analysis lesson, and I get a question that how to determine to the space complexity of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
algorithms ?

> The depth of recursion is only O(log n) for linked list merge-sort
>
> The amount of extra storage space needed for contiguous quick sort is O(n).

**My thoughts:**

Both use divide-and-conquer strategy, so I guess the space complexity of linked list merge sort should be same as the contiguous quick sort. Actually I opt for O(log n) because before every iteration or recursion call the list is divided in half.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worst case depth of recursion for quicksort is not (necessarily) O(log n), because quicksort doesn't divide the data "in half", it splits it around a pivot which may or may not be the median. It's possible to implement quicksort to address this[*], but presumably the O(n) analysis was of a basic recursive quicksort implementation, not an improved version. That would account for the discrepancy between what you say in the blockquote, and what you say under "my thoughts".

Other than that I think your analysis is sound - neither algorithm uses any extra memory other than a fixed amount per level of recursion, so depth of recursion dictates the answer.

Another possible way to account for the discrepancy, I suppose, is that the O(n) analysis is just wrong. Or, "contiguous quicksort" isn't a term I've heard before, so if it doesn't mean what I think it does ("quicksorting an array"), it might imply a quicksort that's necessarily space-inefficient in some sense, such as returning an allocated array instead of sorting in-place. But it would be silly to compare quicksort and mergesort on the basis of the depth of recursion of the mergesort vs. the size of a copy of the input for the quicksort.

[*] Specifically, instead of calling the function recursively on both parts, you put it in a loop. Make a recursive call on the smaller part, and loop around to do the bigger part, or equivalently push (pointers to) the larger part onto a stack of work to do later, and loop around to do the smaller part. Either way, you ensure that the depth of the stack never exceeds log n, because each chunk of work *not* put on the stack is at most half the size of the chunk before it, down to a fixed minimum (1 or 2 if you're sorting purely with quicksort).

Comment: I think the not-so-well-chosen-pivot in quick sort might account for the discrepancy.On the other hand,"contiguous quicksort" is exact “quicksorting an array",as for you implementing optimization,i need to read more to understand what you expressed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the term "contiguous quicksort". But quicksort can have either O(n) or O(log n) space complexity depending on how it is implemented.

If it is implemented as follows:

```
quicksort(start,stop) {
    m=partition(start,stop);
    quicksort(start,m-1);
    quicksort(m+1,stop);
}
```

Then the space complexity is **O(n)**, not O(log n) as is commonly believed. 
This is because you are pushing onto the stack twice at each level, so the space complexity is determined from the recurrance:

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/2)
```

Assuming the partitioning divides the array into 2 equal parts (best case). The solution to this according to the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) is T(n) = O(n).

If we replace the second quicksort call with tail recursion in the code snippet above, then you get T(n) = T(n/2) and therefore T(n) = O(log n) (by case 2 of the Master theorem).

Perhaps the "contiguous quicksort" refers to the first implementation because the two quicksort calls are next to each other, in which case the space complexity is **O(n)**.